# how am i able to change value of same String?

Tags: java, string

i know Strings are immutable in java and i just read some theory about it
Once a String is declared it cannot be changed . i declared a String and changed it's value just by appending some value to it . it should not have happened

```
   String s = "amol";
   s = s + "abc";
   System.out.println(s); //output is amolabc
```

Comment: You didn't change the `String`. You created a new one and assigned it to the same variable.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_concat.htm

Comment: @bradimus so now `s` points to amolabc instead of amol ?

Comment: you need to learn string pool and how to store string value in string pool. you will get answer.

Comment: @Amol you can also work with the String object to stich strings and make char arrays strings and things like that.

Comment: Note that you can still break immutability of String using *reflection*

Answer (score 1):

The String `s` didn't get changed. When you did `s + "abc"`, it created a new `String` object with the result of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of String Pool in Java. Please go through the link 
http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html

Answer (score 0):

You are right that Strings are immutable. Here, You didn't change the String s. All distinct Strings are stored in the Heap Memory. So, all the variables (say 10 variables ) containing the same String (say "Hello" ) will occupy only 5 bytes of memory. They all will point to the same location. Separate instances will not be stored for each of those variables.
Here, when you write s = s + "abc", a new string "amolabc" is created in the heap,and now the variable s just points to the new string in the heap. You didn't modify the value of "amol". You just made a new String.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `immutable` is not like you thought to be.Being immutable guarantees that `hashcode` will always the same, so that it can be cashed without worrying the changes.That means, there is no need to calculate `hashcode` every time it is used.

here you are `appending` another string value to it,which can be done.But you cannot `concatenate` with another string.

By appending it is creating another string.

Refer [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-string)